# Trying to locate an element on a page contains "/abc/def"

Tags: nightwatch.js

So I have written a bunch of NW tests for our dev environment. Unfortunately, being new to automated testing and to this product I have learned dev is not the same as our prod env. The difference is the dev login button is 'href*="/abc/def"' and prod is 'href*="www.example.com/abc/def". The parents and classes of these elements are too different to try and use.

I am just creating the pages and wondering if there is a way to store the selector with either a wildcard, like when SQL uses %, or a href.contains??

I apologise if none of this makes sense, I am completely fresh to programming in general.

Comment: What are you trying to achive? Asserting the login-button or do you try to click it?

Comment: Apologies I should have added this, but I am trying to click it to start the login method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click the login button using `browser.click(CSS-Selector)`

The CSS-Selector should look like this: `a[href*="/abc/def"]`

So you end up with: `browser.click(a[href*="/abc/def"])`

The Asterix works as a wildcard wich will look for a substring: [additional information about different approaches](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css3-substring-matching-attribute-selectors)

Comment: I may have not added the correct info again. I am trying to make the test click on the same button in our dev env as well as our prod env. So if I use the above selector it should pick up the button in both envs?
I also assert that the button is present before I click on it.

Comment: I have just tried it and it works perfectly. Thank you very much, I had no idea that is what the "*" after the element means contains. Very helpful